# Definition of “K-fairness” with respect to concurrency?

Tags: concurrency

There are definitions of Absolute, Strong and Weak Fairness available across the internet, but I cannot find a definition of "K-Fairness" property for critical section algorithms (also algorithms that satisfy a 1-fairness or 3-fairness property). Does this actually exist or is this something that was made up to describe a phenomenon that I am not recognizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should look for "bounded fairness", the property that something happens within the next $k$ times, where $k$ is the bound.

Answer (score 0):

It should refer the paper: Ryan Porter, Yoav Shoham and Moshe Tennenholtz, "Fair imposition", *Journal of Economic Theory* 118(2):209–228, 2004. ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jet.2003.11.005), [Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053103003715))

Comment: Could you summarize the definition from the article, and explain how it answers the original question?  ScienceDirect is a paywalled site, and even some very large computing organizations and universities don't have subscriptions (especially since that's an economics journal).  So all that many of us can see is the abstract.

Comment: What should refer to this paper?